# one click inserting and closing via jquery pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

i am trying to build a media gallery, while working on that i am screwed up with inserting image source and closing the pop on same insert click.
here it is, from where i am calling my popup and ajax

```
<div class="place"></div>
<div class="popup_bk" id="popup_bk"></div>
<div class="popup_gal" id="popup_bk"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function close (){
    $(".popup_gal").hide(); 
    $(".popup_bk").hide();
  }
  $('.actlink').click(function() {
    $(".popup_gal").load("http://gtc.app/admin/media/gallery/").fadeIn('slow'); 
    $(".popup_bk").fadeIn('slow');
  });
  $('.popup_bk').click(function() {
    close();
  });
});
</script>
```

and the other gallery page which is loaded via load (ajax) call is

```
<input type="checkbox" class="sel_img" value="<?php echo $media->id; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $media->file_path . $media->file_name;?>" class="thumbnail index-thumb">
<input type="button" id="insert" name="insert" value="insert" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" id="insert-btn">    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#insert').click(function(event) {
    var chImg='';
    $('.sel_img:checked').each(function(idx,ele){
      chImg+=$(this).siblings('img').attr('src');
    });
    $('.place').html(chImg);
 });
});
</script>
```

so can any help me with this screwed code, is this a good approach to do so or can be improved
secondly! i want to retrieve my processed data at `<div class="place"></div>` when it clicked on insert button and on the same time the popup should be closed.

Comment: a jsFiddle link will help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks i tried more and its done with this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#insert').click(function(event) {
        var chImg='';
        $('.sel_img:checked').each(function(idx,ele){
                chImg+=$(this).siblings('img').attr('src');

        });
        $('.place').attr('src',chImg);
        $('.popup_gal').css('display','none');
        $('.popup_bk').css('display','none');
        //alert(chImg);
    });
});
```

Comment: the function close() that i used for it was not working properly.